# Delphi Text File and Array

Tags: arrays, delphi

I have the following Scenario: In a textfile (justin#us883) the program must extract the password - us883 check if the password typed in is correct to the one in the list and then make a button visible to enter program: Code that is not working:

```
var  
  textf:textfile;
  oneline,spass,scheck :string;
  place,i,icount :integer;
  Arrpass : array[1..Maxnames] of string;
begin
  scheck := edtpass.Text;
  assignfile(textf,'Userlist.txt');
  reset(textf);
  if fileExists('Userlist.txt')= false then 
    exit;
  while not eof(textf) do
  begin
    Readln(textf, oneline);
    place  := pos('#',oneline);
    delete(oneline,1,place);
    spass := copy(oneline,1,place-1);  // get the us883

    Arrpass[i] := spass;

    for i := Low(Arrpass) to High(Arrpass) do
      if Arrpass[i] = spass then
      begin
        btnenter.Visible := true
      end
      else
        btnenter.Visible := False;
    Showmessage('Wrong Password');

  end;
  closefile(textf);

end;
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want to do it more delphi like:

```
var
 list : TStringList;
 user, password : String;
 i : Integer;
begin
  user := 'user1';
 if fileExists('Userlist.txt')= false then exit;

 list := TStringList.create();
 list.NameValueSeparator := '#';
 list.LoadFromFile('Userlist.txt');
 i := list.IndexOfName(user);
 if i >=0 then begin
   password := list.Values[user];
   // check password

 end;
```

Comment: Best approach. I Think you can accept this one as Answer

Answer (score 0):

Issue 1:

```
 place  := pos('#',oneline);
 delete(oneline,1,place);
 spass := copy(oneline,1,place-1);  // get the us883
```

The third line uses position of `#` that is not more actual (after deletion). 
If you don't expect more symbols after password, just use

```
 spass := oneline;
```

Issue 2:
How Arrpass array sould be filled?
This line `Arrpass[i] := spass;` uses uninitialized variable i. And what is a logic to compare just inserted value with itself? Perhaps you want to fill ArrPass before text reading.

Issue 3:
It is worth to check `if fileExists` before file handling.

Comment: Issue 4: The loop runs over all elements and doesn't stop if a correct one is found. Issue 5: wrong password message if always shown